# Noore had to die thrice

Tags: far-cry-4

Sometimes, one of my colleague comes around to play the game on my system. Yesterday, he finished the mission **Shoot the messenger**. He chose not to kill Noore. A cutscene followed where Noore cuts herself, and drops down to the wild animals. She died and we finished the mission.

Afterwards, we went around roaming the city. A bit later, I noticed that another of "Golden Path" mission is available around the map. Heading on there, lo and behold; it was the same mission. I thought that maybe we didn't save the game or maybe there was some bug. We went back to the arena; the whole chase, fights, sabotage etc. later; we again chose not to kill Noore.

And yet again, there was still the same mission available to us. This third time, I had had to kill Noore.

My question is: Was it really a bug? As far as I can understand from reading the [walkthrough](http://www.ign.com/wikis/far-cry-4/Shoot_the_Messenger), it doesn't mention the player to actually choose to kill her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This must have been a bug. I've played through four times, and two of those times I spared Noore, letting her "remove" herself from the game.

The quest has never reappeared, and there's no logical in-game reason why it would. Also, you shouldn't need to save: after major events like quests on the main story line, the game saves itself.

Comment: I think that can be the only explanation. I asked a few other people about the same situation and none of them had this problem.